# Additivity of characteristic cycle of holonomic D-module

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, d-modules, perverse-sheaves, analytic-geometry

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a holonomic D-module on a complex analytic (or alternatively, algebraic) manifold $X$. One can  attach to it (using a good filtration) a characteristic cycle $Ch(\mathcal{M})$ which is an analytic cycle on $T^*X$ whose components are conic Lagrangian subvarieties and their multiplicities are positive integers (see e. g. Def. 1.8.5 in the book “Analytic D-modules and applications” by Bjoern).

> Is it true that for any short exact sequence of holonomic D-modules 
>   $$0\to \mathcal{M}_1\to \mathcal{M}_2\to \mathcal{M}_3\to 0$$
>   one has 
>   $$Ch(\mathcal{M}_2)=Ch(\mathcal{M}_1)+Ch(\mathcal{M}_3).$$

An answer for algebraic D-modules would be equally useful.

Apologies if the question is too basic. I am not a specialist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn’t this Björk’s [**3.1.4** (p. 130)](https://books.google.com/books?id=iLnnCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA130)?